# An "A" record not always working

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a TeamSpeak server on ts3.example.com.

Within the cPanel of example.com I have added an A record that points to the IP of the teamspeak server (excluding the port of course).

This pointing worked for me with no problem and I was able to connect to the teamspeak server while other people were not able to so I put it down to just propagating and waited the 72hours and more people started to come on, However x amount of those people (including myself) and anyone else that tries have intermittent ability to connect via the A record of ts3.vanrust.com and have to use the IP instead.

A week has passed since this record was set and I'm unable to find any information about others who have experienced this issue, or what could be causing it so any insight to cure insanity would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ask DNS for the A record of ts3.vanrust.com, you get two replies:  101.0.105.98 and 103.13.101.81.  Possibly you wanted only one of those?  In that case, about 50% of attempts to access ts3.vanrust.com will end up with the wrong IP-address.

You also have a problem with your glue records.  If I ask the top level servers for the nameservers of vanrust.com, they reply {ns1,ns2}.radstudios.com.au.  But the radstudios servers claim that {ns1,ns2}.pigspot.com.au are the nameservers for the zone.  You should get that fixed, but it shouldn't be a problem in this case, as all four names answer me when I ask them for A of ts3.vanrust.com.